# UITableView data source change does not trigger UI update on iOS 13

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios13

This only happens on iOS 13.. iOS 12.x works fine.

I have a table view with a search controller, and two datasources, one for the regular functionality and one for the search functionality. (the search functionality is unrelated to the content displayed on the main table content).

After cancelling a search, the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` method is triggered, I switch from the search data source to the main datasource and reload the table view but even though the table view details show that the correct datasource is set, the UI still shows the search data source.
I tried triggering the layout refresh, but no luck.

Worth mentioning that the UITableViewDataSource methods are called on the correct data source, it's just the UI that's out of sync so to speak.

Any idea what could cause such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

If I manually set the search controller inactive, it works: `[self.searchController setActive:NO];`